# How to take Tkinter/Canvas images to make a composite image

Tags: python, wordpress, canvas, tkinter

So, I am new to programming, and I'm currently using Python on a rapsberry pi 3 with Tkinter and Canvas to create an interactive map for students to catalogue animals they see around campus. What I am having trouble with is finding a way to create an image that is a composite of everyone's inputs on their individual maps to display on this new map. What i will do eventually is to embed this code into a wordpress php (i found a code for that already).

One possible thing I was thinking of is to save the image as a postscript document and then use that document for something like Image Magick and somehow have it overlay the images ontop of each other, though im not sure how it would "update"

Here is my code for the interactive map if anyone's interested for python 2.9.7

```
import base64
import Tkinter
import urllib

def getaddress (location, width, height, zoom):
    locationnospaces = urllib.quote_plus(location)
    address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?\
center={0}&zoom={1}&size={2}x{3}&format=gif&sensor=false"\
.format(locationnospaces, zoom, width, height)
    return address

def getmap (location, width, height, zoom):
    address = getaddress(location, width, height, zoom)
    urlreader = urllib.urlopen(address)
    data = urlreader.read()
    urlreader.close()
    base64data = base64.encodestring(data)
    image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(data=base64data)
    return image

def getlabelname():
    popup = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    popup.title("Rabbit Season")
    label = Tkinter.Label(popup, text="Date/Time of Sighting")
    label.pack()

    labelname = Tkinter.StringVar()
    textbox = Tkinter.Entry(popup, textvariable=labelname)
    textbox.pack()
    textbox.focus_force()

    button = Tkinter.Button(popup, text ="Done", command=popup.destroy)
    button.pack()

    popup.wait_window()

    text = labelname.get()
    return text

def canvasclick(event):
    x,y = event.x, event.y
    widget = event.widget
    size = 10
    widget.create_oval(x-size, y-size, x+size, y+size, width=2)
    label = getlabelname()
    widget.create_text(x, y+2*size, text=label)


location = "Adelphi University"
width = 640
height = 480
zoom = 16

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title(location)
window.minsize(width, height)
window.maxsize(width, height)

mapimage = getmap(location, width, height, zoom)
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(window, width=width, height=height)
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=mapimage,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>",canvasclick)
canvas.pack()
window.mainloop()
```